# PHP checkbox array enters "Array" into MySQL Database

Tags: php, mysql

Using the guidance from several Stack Overflow members I've gotten an PHP form to communicate with my MySQL database. Now, I'm using an array for my checkboxes and the information does get to the MySQL table...sort of..

The code below will insert all of the records into the database but the column that the checkboxes correspond to have the value "Array" instead of the assigned values...:

```
<?php
 function renderForm($articletitle, $articleorganization, $articledate, $articleurl,     $articletags )
 {
 ?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="stylized" class="myform">
      <form id="form" name="form" action="" method="post">
. . .
          <input type="checkbox" name="articletags[]" value="checkbox" id="articletags_0" />
          <input type="checkbox" name="articletags[]" value="checkbox 2" id="articletags_1" />
. . .
        <footer><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add this Article"></footer></form>
    </div>
  </body>
</html><?php 
 }
. . .

 if(count($articletags) > 0)
{
 $articletags_string = implode(",", $articletags);
}

 if (isset($_POST['submit']))
 { 
 $articletitle = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['articletitle']));
 $articleorganization = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['articleorganization']));
 $articledate = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['articledate']));
 $articleurl = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['articleurl']));
 $articletags = ($_POST['articletags']);

. . .
 mysql_query("INSERT articles SET articletitle='$articletitle',     articleorganization='$articleorganization', articledate='$articledate',     articleurl='$articleurl', articletags='$articletags' ")
 or die(mysql_error()); 


 header("Location:addsuccess.html"); 
 }
 }
 else

 {
 renderForm('','','','');
 }
?>
```

Comment: On an important side note, you should replace this line...

if (isset($_POST['submit']))

...with this line:

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')


Currently, you're just checking whether a button has been clicked or not. When someone presses enter in your form, your logic will fail.

Comment: Thanks for catching that 132911. Awesome eye.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `$_POST['articletags']` is an array, you have to convert it to string before saving to your table. Replace this line:

```
$articletags = ($_POST['articletags']);
```

with this:

```
$articletags = implode(',', $_POST['articletags']);
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes You are passing array values to your database field..For that You have to do some conversion method.

You can do it one several ways. 
first you can convert your array values into string.

```
$articletags = implode(',', $_POST['articletags']);
```

second you can convery your array values into json format and then you can enter in your database..

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I'm going through this right now, and here's what I'm thinking.

The best way, since you have a many-to-many relationship, is to have three tables, let's call them "main_table", "tag_table", and "key_table".  If I'm not mistaken, this will give you level 3 normalization.

Put the values for your checkboxes in an array.  When you go to upload the info, first upload the other data to "main_table" - don't worry about your tags.  Then get the ID number for the main_table row you just uploaded.

Now use the foreach operator on your "tags" array, and generate a string value to go into your INSERT INTO key_table VALUES $string.

I think this is at least one right way to do it, certainly from the MySQL perspective.  Here's some barebones code that I just wrote and tested.  There are a lot of little bits missing concerning errors, security, etc.

Here is the form, which is going to download and fill the form from the database. (``It does include an auto-value (checked='checked') so that the form will not be erased if there is a problem.)

```
            $query1 = "SELECT * FROM tag_table";
            $res1 = mysqli_query ($dbc, $query1);
            while ($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($res1, MYSQLI_NUM)) {
                    $tag_id = $row1[0];
                    $tag = $row1[1];
                    echo "<div class='check'><label for='tags[]'>$tag</label> "; 
                    echo "<input type='checkbox' name='tags[]' value='$tag_id'";
                    if (in_array("$tags",$tag_id)) echo " checked='checked' ";
                    echo "/></div>";
                }
```

Here are the barebones of the form handler, where you have already established a database connection held by the variable $dbc.  This goes immediately after you have uploaded the basic information, so that mysqli_insert_id will grab the id number of the most recent insertion:

```
    $tags = $_POST (tags);
    if ($tags) {
        $new_main_id =  mysqli_insert_id($dbc);
    foreach ($tags as $value) {
           $qvalues .= "('$new_main_id','$value'),";
    }
    $qvalues = substr("$qvalues", 0, -1); 

    $q2 = "INSERT INTO key_table (id_main,id_tag_table) VALUES $qvalues";
    $res2 = mysqli_query($dbc, $q2);

}
```

This will give you a nice & clean normalized database.  Notice that we use the PHP function substr() to take the comma off the last of the list of values to be inserted.

So if you had a tag table with three rows of two columns, say, 1 red, 2 blue, 3 green, and your user had checked red and green, and the id number in your main_table for your main insertion was 18, the query ($q2) would read:

INSERT INTO key_table (id_main,id_tag_table) VALUES ('18','1'),('18','3')